What is this purple and orange flower I found blooming during spring in my backyard in Östergötland, Sweden?
Two weeks ago I picked a flower from my backyard near my compost in Östergötland, Sweden and pressed it. Now, I realise that I don't actually know what kind of flower this is. I tried using Pl@ntNet identify and it gave me some promising suggestions, namely crocus nudiflorus and crocus speciosus.
However, the former blooms in autumn and this one was picked — and clearly blooming — in spring. Additionally, one source (unfortunately not in English), claims that it does not reproduce in Sweden, so it seems strange to me that it would appear in my backyard then given that it was not planted there (but I could be wrong about this being relevant, please correct me if that's the case).
The latter flowers in October, so it doesn't seem likely to be the right one either. It also doesn't look quite right to me.
While trying to find good sources for my claims I stumbled upon crocus vernus which seems to fit the bill given that it reproduces in Sweden and blooms in spring, but I'm not
sure how to verify this.
What kind of flower could the one in the picture below be?


@YosefBaskin no answers in comments, please. Yes, this includes half-answers. A few more details on how you came to your conclusion would also be helpful and appreciated.

Why do think it's not Crocus Vernus? Are you colder than Aberdeen, Scotland?

@YosefBaskin Mostly a lack of experience with identifying plants. A quick look at timeanddate.com would suggest that Aberdeen has a similar temperature to where I live.

This flower is pretty obscure but it appears to be a Bieberstein's Crocus (Crocus speciosus) in the genus Crocus of the family Iridaceae. It matches the photo as it has 6 petals and the pistil and stamen appear to match quite well.
The flower blooms primarily in the fall, but is found more than frequently in full bloom in the spring

